# Ways to develop an online multiplayer game?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, multiplayer

I developed a little **2D game** in `Java` recently without any external package.

However, I am interested in a new project that would require online `multiplayer` for `Android` (and possibly **Linux/Windows** as well).

First of all, I have no knowledge yet in `Android` development, nor in `network development`. I have no idea where to start looking at so this is why I ask about this.

So far, I've read about using **libGDX** for `multiplatform advantages`. I'm planning to learn how to use it but I've yet to understand how developing an online game differs from developing a local multiplayer game. So here are my questions:

- Can I develop a `local multiplayer game` using **libGDX** and add online multiplayer easily ? Or should I rather start developing it with online in mind from scratch?
- Is there any recommended guide I could read about developing `multiplayer games`?
- Can I develop my **libGDX** game without worrying about `Android`, and then add touch inputs when I port it?

Comment: This is basically a "I have no experience and no idea, but how do I develop this hugely complicated potentially many man-year project" question.

Comment: The project I have in mind is nothing complicated to be honest. Taking apart learning how to do a multiplayer game, it shouldn't take more than a few weeks to be done. The issue is that I have no knowledge on multiplayer games development so it makes things a bit complicated.

Comment: Roukira having built a game has experience and wants to take the next step. While a 3D multiplayer shooter may be a multi-man-year project, I could probably hack together an online multiplayer tic-tac-toe with LibGDX in a couple of days.

Comment: Yes, calling it a project might be a bit too much. It will be a simple 2D game. It's mostly a test project to get to learn how online multiplayer games work.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer all your questions positively. My friends and I have developed an application with libgdx and we have also published it on the play store. For the moment it is only on Android, but it has multiplatform advantages that we will use shortly. We are adding online multiplayer and it is not complicated. If you want to see it, the name is ["Cetriolino"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mwm.cetriolino).

Comment: Checking it out !

Answer (score 1):

> Can I develop a local multiplayer game using libGDX and add online
>   multiplayer easily ? Or should I rather start developing it with
>   online in mind from scratch?

Designing multiplayer first is the way to go, since the game engine you are making require a different kind of logic to support multiplayer. Going single player first and then multiplayer risk requiring a major refactoring.

> Is there any recommended guide I could read about developing
>   multiplayer games?

Yes there are many, but which one depends on the kind of game, search amazon / google.

> Can I develop my libGDX game without worrying about Android, and then add touch inputs when I port it?

Yes, but the porting will be easier if you only use such inputs that are available on both platforms, such as click / drag / zoom.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm planning to develop a simple 2D game.
I was thinking that local multiplayer shouldn't be that much different from online multiplayer if I have in mind the possibility of it being online from start.

Comment: Local multiplayer and online multiplayer are less different, I misunderstood that part.